# Is this function $2\pi$-periodic?

Tags: calculus, summation, periodic-functions

If I construct $$G(x) =\sum_{1}^{\infty} g(x +2n\pi),$$ does this make $G(x)$ $2\pi$-periodic?  My understanding is that if $G(x)$ were now $2\pi$-periodic, then that means $G(x) = G(x + 2\pi$) = G(x + $4\pi$), and so on...

does the $2\pi$ and the $4\pi$ just get "absorbed" into the $2n\pi$ in the summation?

Thanks,

Comment: No, it doesn't. $G(x+2\pi)=G(x)-g(x+2\pi)$. You need $$G(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(x+2n\pi)$$ And of course, you need the function to actually be defined. That is, the sum needs to converge for all $x$.

Comment: How does summing over the negative integers help make the function become periodic?  Is there some sort of cancellation / telescoping sum effect?

Comment: It just that the set of values $\{x+2\pi n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $\{x+2\pi + 2\pi n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ are the same.

Comment: or is summing over the negative integers, too, now making the $2\pi$, $4\pi$ get absorbed in the $2n\pi$ in the summation?

Comment: You keep using that word "absorbed." I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Ah, your explanation of the sets of values being equal is what I meant by "absorbed".  Ok, I got it now.  Thanks so much, @ThomasAndrews.